# Can't parse a rss feed

Tags: java, android, saxparser

I can't parse this rss site: http://vnexpress.net/rss/tin-moi-nhat.rss. My sax parser just recognize 2 tags "meta" and "script" while it works very well with some other rss site. Anyone can help me this?
Here is the code:

```
public class RssParseHandler extends DefaultHandler {

  private List<RssItem> rssItems;

  private RssItem currentItem;

  private boolean parsingTitle;

  private boolean parsingLink;

  public RssParseHandler() {
    rssItems = new ArrayList<RssItem>();
  }

  public List<RssItem> getItems() {
    return rssItems;
  }

  @Override
  public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    if ("item".equals(qName)) {
        currentItem = new RssItem();
    } else if ("title".equals(qName)) {
        parsingTitle = true;
    } else if ("link".equals(qName)) {
        parsingLink = true;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
    if ("item".equals(qName)) {
        rssItems.add(currentItem);
        currentItem = null;
    } else if ("title".equals(qName)) {
        parsingTitle = false;
    } else if ("link".equals(qName)) {
        parsingLink = false;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    if (parsingTitle) {
        if (currentItem != null)
            currentItem.setTitle(new String(ch, start, length));
    } else if (parsingLink) {
        if (currentItem != null) {
            currentItem.setLink(new String(ch, start, length));
        }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Improved code formatting

Comment: Is it valid and well-formed?